# How to change footer and header for a CMS page only using layout XML?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, cms-block, cms-pages

I want to change out the footer and header for a minimized version but only on a certain CMS Page.

Is it possible to do this with the layout XML input field to remove the header/footer and add static blocks in their places?

I do not have access to Magento files.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what theme you are using and may need to find out what your block names are but this should do the trick

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="cms/block" name="custom_footer">
        <action method="setBlockId">
        <block_id>your-static-block</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
<reference name="footer">
        <remove name="footer_links" />
        <remove name="footer_links2" />
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Dava. We're using a modified version of rwd. How can I get ahold of the block names without having access to the source files?

Comment: But inserting content works fine, so I guess if everything else fails, I could hide the old footer with CSS. What is the reference to add something in front of the header, though?

Comment: @NoahWetjen the reference for that is after_body_start

Comment: `after_body_start` doesn't work for me. I'm using the same code, just changed `_end` to `_start`.

Comment: @NoahWetjen that could mean its been removed as that works fine on my version of RWD

Answer (score 0):

To remove header & footer :
1: Update design with empty layout
2: add particular static block on cms by following way
add below live in page content:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="static-block-to-use-in-cms-page"}}
```

Let me know if you still have an issue in it

Comment: @noah-wetjen its perfect fit for your issue let me know if its not working.